# Bootstrap grid not centering? What am I doing wrong

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm working on the Free code camp project, but I've hit a snag. I cannot get the paragraph text below the image to center. I have the  set to grid 4.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h1 class="text-center text-uppercase">Bernie Sanders</h1>
        <em><h2 class="text-center">"The man who stands for the people"</h2></em>
        <img id="bernie" src="https://imgur.com/iw13OaU.jpg" alt="Bernie Sanders">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
          <h3 class="text-center" id="timeline">A timeline of Bernie Sanders Accomplishments</h3>
          <ul class="text-justify small" id="list">
          ...
```

https://codepen.io/thehiddencheese/pen/WMWJeW

Comment: You want image and text below image in middle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First wrap your `grid 4` to the `.row` and use bootstrap **[[Flex Utilities]](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content)** `.justify-content-center` class to that row like

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Another solution will be to use **[[offset]](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns)** classes like

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 offset-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center` for the div `<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">` then the paragraph text will be aligned to the center of the page below the image.

But, it's looking odd with the bullet points and text aligned to center. If you are aligning it to the center I suggest going without bullets :).

Below is the div tag you can use.

```
<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4" style=" text-align:  center;">
```

Comment: I think I might have fixed it, does it look that way now?

Comment: it is pretty good now